# Applyin GTK themes to Dolphin?

Tags: themes, gtk, qt, dolphin

Is there a way to apply GNOME GTK theme (I use GNOME 40.5 and Ubuntu 21.10) to Dolphin File manager?
As Dolphin is QT, I guess I cannot apply the same exact theme used by GNOME on that, but if there is a way to apply themes on Dolphin maybe I can at least find an adequate theme and use that beside my GNOME theme.

Comment: I would think that is a question for the support team for that product. https://github.com/dolphin-emu/dolphin/wiki/Building-with-Qt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot apply directly GTK theme to QT app, but you can apply QT styles that recreates GTK look and feel.
These styles are available after installing the packages:

`sudo apt install qt5-style-kvantum qt5-style-kvantum-themes`

Then, you need to tell to your system to use `kvantum` style for QT5 apps. This is performed by setting the `QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE` variable in your `.profile` file.

You have two alternative ways.

*Alternative 1*

- run `echo "export QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE=kvantum" >> $HOME/.profile`

*Alternative 2:*

- open the file with `gedit $HOME/.profile`
- add the line (if not present) `export QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE=kvantum`
- save the file.

After changing the `.profile` file, you have to logout from your account and login, then it will be sourced once automatically.

Now, open the Kvantum Manager app from the app-grid menu:

- Click on the submenu "Change/Delete Theme"
- Select "KvYaru" from "Select Menu".
- Click "Use this theme" button.

[image: Kvantum Manager]

This is the way to activate a style that resembles the default Ubuntu theme, called Yaru. By default, a lots of themes are installed, so you can choose what you prefer.

The Kvantum project is available at [this GitHub page](https://github.com/tsujan/Kvantum/tree/master/Kvantum).